Chrome Browser: Task Manager Refresh Rate = Too Fast
Chrome's task manager is a useful tool, but the refresh rate is far too fast.
It is very hard to:

Click on jumping tasks
Read both task and data
Get a practical understanding of tab activity

Can anything be done about this?
Is a separate tool available?
Tried:

Taking rapid screenshots (can't capture full list and cross comparison is impossible due to reordering)
Screen recording and slowing footage (helps, but can't capture full list or interact with it)
Searching for settings (none)
Searching for alternatives (none, and even if there were, they seem like they would be far too invasive)
Teaching self about subframes and dedicated workers (good to know, but unable to collapse list accordingly, so it is bloated and this reduces what is visible on one page which further worsens the effect of the rapid changing order)
Teaching myself what additional columns represented (data not helpful, only memory footprint and CPU really matter)

I have tried to:
Learn things that lead to a dead end.
Do things that make me look foolish and don't work.
Find modifications that aren't there.
Interpret harder, learning better, clicking faster and reading stronger
